# Polynomial array not working

Tags: java, arrays, polynomials

Just to preface this, it *is* for school so I'm not looking for straight answers just helpful advice. I'm limited to what built-in methods I can use. Basically I'm to take a polynomial into array p. Then take another into p1. Finally add those together. For some reason I get the error "array required, but Polynomial found" and I'm not sure why. The teacher also has it set up to return a double value but I'm unsure why. Disregard the multiplication portion. Everything else works as intended. Any tips would be appreciated.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Polynomial {
    final int MAXSIZE = 20;

    int p[]; //coefficient
    int n;   //degree

    //array constructor
    Polynomial() {
        p = new int [MAXSIZE];
        n = -1;
    }

    void readP() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter degree: "); 
        n = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a p[" + i + "]:"); 
            p[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void printP() {
        if (p[0] < 0)
            System.out.printf("-");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (p[i] != 0) {
                if (p[i] > 1)
                    System.out.printf(p[i] + "x^" + (n-i));
                else if (p[i] == 1)
                    System.out.printf("x^" + (n-i));

                if (p[i] < -1)
                    System.out.printf(p[i] * -1 + "x^" + (n-i));
                else if (p[i] == -1)
                    System.out.printf("x^" + (n-i));

                if (p[i+1] < 0)
                    System.out.printf(" - ");
                else
                    System.out.printf(" + ");
            }
        if (p[n] > 0)
            System.out.print(p[n]);
        else
            System.out.print(p[n] * -1);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    double evalP(double x) {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
            total += (p[i] * (Math.pow(x, i)));
        total += p[n];
        System.out.println();
        return total;
    }

    double addP(Polynomial P1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] = p[i] + P1[i];
        return total;
    }

    double multiplyP(Polynomial P1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] += p[i] * P1[i];
        return p;
    }
}

public class Lab5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Polynomial myPoly = new Polynomial();
        String res;
        Polynomial p1;

        do { 
            System.out.println("1. Read Polynomial");
            System.out.println("2. Print Polynomial");
            System.out.println("3. Evaluate Polynomial");
            System.out.println("4. Add Polynomial");
            System.out.println("5. Multiply Polynomial");

            System.out.println("Q. Quit");

            System.out.print("Select: ");
            res = in.next();
            System.out.println();

            switch (res.charAt(0)) {
                case '1':
                    myPoly.readP();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    myPoly.printP();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    System.out.print("Enter x: ");
                    double x = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print(myPoly.evalP(x));
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    p1 = new Polynomial();
                    p1.readP();
                    myPoly.addP(p1);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    p1 = new Polynomial();
                    p1.readP();
                    myPoly.multiplyP(p1);
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'Q': case 'q':
                    System.out.println("Bye!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid!");
                    System.out.println();
            }
        } while (res.charAt(0) != 'Q' && res.charAt(0) != 'q');
    }   
}
```

Comment: What line gives you this error?

Comment: Your Polynomial class is not an array, so you can't use syntax like `P1[i]` on an instance of it.  I think you meant something like `P1.p[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

These two method will both break as is. As azurefrog pointed out, P1 is a Polynomial object, not an Array, and so it can't handle the bracket syntax.

```
double addP(Polynomial P1) {//P1 is a Polynomial
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = p[i] + P1[i];
//can't use P1[i] syntax here. 
//Java will not guess that you intended to access the 'p' field of P1
    return total;
}

double multiplyP(Polynomial P1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] += p[i] * P1[i];//you'll probably have the same issue here as well
    return p;
}
```

You need to access the Polynomial's Array field 'p' before you can use the bracket syntax. As in:

```
P1.p[i], not P1[i]
```

which would give you:

```
double addP(Polynomial P1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = p[i] + P1.p[i];
    return total;
}
```

Finally, if you're using Eclipse or some other IDE, you can set a breakpoint for an Exception and then examine the data at the moment it breaks. Also, you can enter expressions and make sure you're getting what you expect.

Comment: You should also point out that both `addP` and `multiplyP` should be `void`

Comment: Yes, that code is broken, but I assume that the OP has not gotten to those problems due to the error they're getting with the Array syntax problem. Also, those problems are not related to the question's title or body: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308807/do-i-solve-users-problem-or-answer-the-question and my answer will solve the issue that is being explicitly questioned. OP may find the answer to the other problems elsewhere - they are very different problems. If the question is edited, I will adjust my answer to match the current state.